# Problema con UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

Estoy haciendo un proyecto, y empece con uno que Xcode te da por defecto, funciona bien, pero quiero dejar el recuadro de login que sea estático para cuando hagan scroll se mantenga siempre, solo cambie algún contenido de el label de arriba, pero el UIViewController de la derecha se sobrepone y no me deja dar clic sobre los botones y los text Fields, alguien sabe si puedo continuar así o simplemente hacerlo de otra manera ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si solo quieres que haya scroll en una parte del VC, por qué no metes ahí un collection view pequeño con scroll horizontal? Normalmente un pageViewController se usa cuando quieres cambiar todo el contenido de la pantalla y quizá dejar algún elemento estático como un label, o un botón, pero no al revés!

Comment: si gracias, es fue lo que hice al final